# There is no description on the character creation page of RuneScape?

Tags: runescape

I just started playing on RuneScape, well, actually, I haven't started playing yet. I'm on the character creation screen and there are different kinds of clothes designs, some with weapons, some without. I don't know what each of them specifically do. Why are there no descriptions as to what that certain class is?

Here's a screenshot of one without weapon.
[image]

And here's a screenshot of the other one with a weapon.
[image]

Comment: I'm not really sure what clothing with weapons you are referring to. Can you perhaps provide a screenshot?

Comment: Screenshot added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Runescape, all clothing and other appearance options affect only the appearance of the character. They don't matter at all to stats or anything else in game. You will also have the option to change them after you start playing.

Runescape does not have a class system. All characters can learn the same skills equally well, and no choices you make when you start or while playing will prevent you from learning a certain skill or doing a certain quest.

Comment: Ahh, that makes a lot more sense! But for example, if I choose the style that has a weapon, will my character spawn with, say, a sword if I chose the one with it? Or is that only for character preview? (See my 2nd screenshot)

Comment: I actually don't know (the character creator has changed several times since I started), but whatever you choose, you should be able to easily get training versions of any of the weapon styles after you start.

Comment: It doesn't choose the weapon. During the tutorial, you will be made to use all the weapons, just to give you an understanding of the skills. Good luck on your character, it is a fun game, despite what majority of people say